# Is this a thread safe vector, and if so why do some methods of std::vector require locking for thread safety while others do not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, thread-safety

As a complete newby to threading I've done some poking around in search for an implementation of a thread safe std::vector. Based (heavily) on my reading I've come up with this:

```
    # include <vector>

    template<class ContainedType>
    class ThreadSafeVector {
    public:
        ThreadSafeVector()
                : vec_(), mut_(), cond_() {}

        explicit ThreadSafeVector(std::vector<ContainedType> vec)
                : vec_(vec), mut_(), cond_() {};

        ThreadSafeVector(std::initializer_list<ContainedType> vec)
                : vec_(std::vector<ContainedType>(vec.begin(), vec.end())), mut_(), cond_() {};

        ~ThreadSafeVector() = default;

        void insert(ContainedType in, int index) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut_);
            vec_[index] = std::move(in);
            cond_.notify_one();
        }

        void push_back(ContainedType in) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut_);
            vec_.push_back(in);
            cond_.notify_one();
        }

        ContainedType &operator[](int index) {
            return vec_[index];
        }

        typename std::vector<ContainedType>::iterator begin() {
            return vec_.begin();
        }

        typename std::vector<ContainedType>::iterator end() {
            return vec_.end();
        }

        std::vector<ContainedType> toVector(){
            return vec_;
        }

    private:
        std::vector<ContainedType> vec_;
        std::mutex mut_;
        std::condition_variable cond_;
    };
```

First question, is this a thread safe implementation of vector? Second question if yes, then why do `push_back` and `insert` require calls to `lock_guard` and `cond_.notify` while `operator[]`, `begin()` and `end()` do not? Thanks

Comment: `>>` https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Fyi, `vec_.push_back(mut_);` is nonsense. That's pushing the mutex into the internal vector; not the by-value object `in`. One of many things broken in this code (and no, it's not safe; that's just one of its problems).

Comment: @WhozCraig just a typo, thanks.

Comment: If the goal is to protect the vector object whilst simultaneously disregarding any safety for the actual *content*, maybe. If the latter is important (and it *is* important) then its a *long* way off. One need only consider the iterators being returned, which are hot on the internal vector, and object modification therein is completely off the protection grid. I also see no sense for the condition variable whatsoever. It's signaled on push and insert, but being private, no exposure exists for anyone to actually be listening.

Comment: consider that thread safety comes at a price. You want to keep locks only when needed, as short as possible, and do as much as possible during one lock of the mutex. Not the best example, but when a loop pushes 100 elements you rather want to lock a mutex once not 100 times. Also note that you only synchronize insertion but accessing the elements is not thread-safe

Comment: `Queue` is better candidate for thread safety. vector's interface is not adapted for thread safety.

Comment: Here's a thread safe vector:  `std::vector<int const> const thread_safe_vec{1, 2, 3};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not thread safe.

Thread 1 can go into:

```
ContainedType &operator[](int index) 
    {
        return vec_[index];
    }
```

and have just computed the reference `ContainedType &` and has just written it to the return value. Then Thread 2 goes into:

```
void push_back(ContainedType in) {
```

And the vector gets invalidated, thus the reference gets invalidated too. Boom.

Comment: You make good point, but when someone asks "is this thread safe?", I believe pointing out a thread safety issue is valid. Even if the whole solution suffers from other problems.

Comment: Jarods point is your case isn't safe *period*, Regular `std::vector` suffers from precisely the same condition, and is covered by the iterator, pointer and reference invalidation rules as described in the standard, without bringing threads into the picture whatsoever. In short, this isn't a reason it's not thread-safe; it's a reason why, when used in poorly constructed code, it's not safe *at all*.

Comment: Thanks to all for grilling my code and probably saving me a lot of headache in future. Back to the textbook for me it seems. I'll look into using a Queue as suggested by @Jarod42

Comment: no reallocations needed to go Boom. Just have two threads call `operator[]` and write to the reference